# s2s, auto encoders/RNN/LSTM for simulating mouse movements

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

Does anyone have any advice/blobs as to whether or not it is possible to build a s2s neural network model to simulate real human mouse behaviour?

My current thinking is that an auto-encoder could take a final destination `(x,y)` point and be given a sequence of `(x,y)` coordinates that lead up to that destination.

Do you guys think it would be possible to have a 1 to many model that given a destination to get to it provides a sequence of mouse `(x,y)` coordinates to get there?

Training data looks like:

```
destination(x,y)
sequence[(x1,y1), .... (x10,y10)]...
```